# Joomla adds two identical records to SQL table

Tags: mysql, joomla2.5

Using this php script in a Joomla environment I always get two absolutely identical records appended to the sql table. I have checked the query string and that looks ok - so I'm at a loss!

```
$writetwo = "INSERT INTO #__art_visits VALUES('','$ua','$prod','$man','$dev','$os',NOW())";
$db->setQuery($writetwo);
$db->query();
```

Earlier in the script there are queries on the table, but I'm not sure that this has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: you have set of values right? the first column `VALUES(''`,is it an auto incremented column? what do you mean by identical records appended? all columns have identical data?

Comment: there is a a similar script subject to an if condition where I used $writeone - but I get the double record addition whether or not this other condition is tru or false

Comment: by record I mean two new absolutely identical rows

Comment: when you set the column as autoincrement,don't pass an empty string, it's different from null. instead `INSERT... VALUES(NULL, ....)`

Comment: (and the other $writeone script also has an autoincrement, but here there is no problem - the only substantial difference is that the $writetwo contains a NOW() value - could this be the problem?)

Comment: changing to NULL didn't help ...

Comment: if you run the sql directly on the database does it also insert two rows? could there be a trigger on the row? another option - could there be something ajax-y happening on the page that's inserting a row that you're not considering?

Comment: You need to post all of the code. This snippet of code in isolation will only insert a single row to the table unless it runs multiple times. We need to see what else is going on in the code causing your issue.

Comment: Where is this snippet called? Is it from a component or a plugin? Some events in plugins are called multiple times during a page load or a article save, and if this appears in one of them then you will have multiple posts.